# How can I open KDE on Windows Bash?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, kde, tty

I have installed `kubuntu-desktop` on my Windows Bash and xming server on Windows. I can normally start apps like `firefox`, but when I try `startx`, I get error:

```
xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (No such file or directory)
```

How can I fix it please? Is there any method, how to create virtual tty0 redirecting to xming server or VNC client?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**startx** doesn't "use" xming. **xming** is an X server; startx launches its own (different) X server.

If you're only trying to launch a graphical environment, then you don't need to run startx if you already have xming installed and configured. Directly launch the application that you want to run.

If you want to run a graphical environment, then you should try "unity".

Note: Graphical stuff may not work well as WSL has not yet implemented 100% of the Linux kernel's functionality, and kernel features that are used mostly or entirely by graphical applications have not been a priority so far. Its only for development purpose.

Thank you.

Comment: In your profile, you say you like `county music`. Is that some sort of music played in your county offices? Couldn't think of anything else...  ;-)

Comment: Well, so you've asked! [That](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_music) should explain all.  Thanks.

Comment: it's "country" not "county"